# textbox readonly validation php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I have a Datepicker and I want to have validation and it is in readonly but my code doesn't work perfectly. please help.

This is my js for error trapping

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

 $( "#jQueryValidateTest" ).validate();

 $( "[type=readonly]" ).datepicker({
 onClose: function() {
  $( this ).valid();
    }
    });
    });​
  </script>
```

And here is my form

```
                    <form  id="jQueryValidateForm"action="reservation/demo.php" method="post"" >
                    <span style="margin-right: 11px;">Start Date: <input type="readonly"
                    name="start" id="sd" value="" maxlength="10" required=""/></span><br>
                    <span style="margin-right: 11px;">End Date:<input type="readonly" 
                    name="end" id="ed" value="" maxlength="10" required="" /></span>    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="result" id="result" /><br>
                    <span><input type="submit" onclick="setDifference(this.form); validateForm();"  value="CHECK AVAILABILITY");" /></span>
                    </form>
```

PROBLEM SOLVED!!!

Comment: `'readonly'=>'readonly'` is not valid Javascript. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: I just try it. I need to have a validation in my Start and End date that is readonly.

Comment: You already have `readonly="readonly"` in the HTML. What are you trying to do in the Javascript? There's no `=>` operator in Javascript. And your parentheses aren't balanced.

Answer (score 0):

These lines are syntactically incorrect

```
if (x==null || x=="")
    'readonly'=>'readonly'));
```

and

```
if (y==null || y=="")
    'readonly'=>'readonly'));
```

Did you mean to put `||` or `&&`? Also they don't really seem to make sense.

You should probably remove the `'readonly'=>'readonly'));` bits.

Comment: Does this code validation works? $(function() {

  $( "#jQueryValidateTest" ).validate();

  $( "[type=readonly]" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
      $( this ).valid();
    }
  });
});​

Comment: I don't know, give it a go. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

1. readonly is not a method and takes no assignments; it is an attribute.
2. Reference dom object by ID, not by NAME.